# Prevent keyTyped() from triggering when pressing ctrl+s

Tags: java, events, swing

I have an accelerator for ctrl+s and at the same time a keylistener on a JTextField listening for keyTyped(). But when i press ctrl+s i dont want it to trigger keyTyped(). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you listening for "key typed" events on the text field?

Probably a better solution is to use a DocumentListener to be notified when text is added or removed from the text field.

If you state your actual requirement, not your solution we may be able to give other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the event

> e.consume();

Comment: He could. But where? He won't get a KeyEvent when using an Accelerator.

Comment: He says he doesn't want it to trigger, so he can just consume it at the start?

Comment: Yes, but only on ctrl+s. If he just put e.consume() at the top of his KeyTyped() he would consume every KeyEvent, not just when ctrl+s is pressed